# Import latest file from S3 bucket to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

**SITUATION**

I have written some code in Python 3 in which I use the OS and Glob packages to find the latest csv file in a directory and convert it to a Panda dataframe.

Code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import glob
import os

# LOOK FOR ALL CSVs IN FOLDER AND GET LATEST
fld = '.'
latest_csv_file = glob.glob('/path/to/file/filename.csv')

imported_file = max(latest_csv_file, key=os.path.getctime)


# IMPORT LATEST CV USING PANDAS
imported_file = pd.read_csv(latest_csv_file, dtype={2:'str'})


# REMOVE SPACES FROM COL NAMES AND CONVERT COL NAMES TO LOWER CASE
imported_file.columns = imported_file.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
imported_file.columns = imported_file.columns.str.lower()
```

This seems to work well, however I need to be able to perform the same operation in my Lambda fuction, which saves a csv file attachment from an incoming email.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

```
 bucketname = 'my_bucket' 
    
    
 s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
 response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket = bucketname2, Prefix = 'attachments/')
 all = response['Contents']      
 latest_file = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
    
 print(latest_file)
```

This will give me the name of the file in the following format

> attachments/nolu34lqipv1cl14i0qjebcc1rnqb2ngbnf4ss01-filename.csv
>
> [folder]/[original_msg_key]-[filename.csv]

However if I try and read the file into a Pandas df I get the follwoing

```
imported_file = pd.read_csv(latest_file, dtype={2:'str'})
```

> module initialization error Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>

I understand this to be because Pandas is expecting a specific file path and not an object of type 'dict', but can't see how to achieve my aim.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the key of your object, you have to use `latest_file['Key']` and for pandas you should include `s3://` as a prefix:

```
imported_file = pd.read_csv('s3://' + latest_file['Key'], dtype={2:'str'})
```

This will require [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) correctly setup for your python along with AWS credentials for S3 access.

You also have `bucketname2` where `bucketname` should be used.

Comment: Thnaks @Marcin. Is this what is referred to as 'mounting' an S3 bucket?

Comment: @jimiclapton I think the "mounting" would refer to the use of [s3fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) in which the s3 would look like any other folder in your OS for all applications to use. But `s3fs` is just an interface to s3 specific to python and pandas.

Comment: Interesting, ok. 
Attempted to install via Cloud9 using `sudo pip install s3fs` and get installation succes s message, yet lambda error logs say `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 's3fs'` when using `import s3fs`

Comment: Is it possible this has to be imported and used as a layer in Lambda function, like I had to do with the Pandas installation?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this in lambda. Tack it on to your existing code

```
bucketname = 'my_bucket'  
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
key = latest_file #validate this is the full key path

obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key)
data = io.StringIO(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
pd.read_csv(data) # use additional arguments as needed
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @Jonathan Leon, I will try this.
Did you possibly mean `obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=key)`. I believe this would throw a `not defined` error otherwise.

Comment: yes, i didn't catch that change in my code vs yours when I copied it in. Updated the code to reflect it.